# Como limpar os inputs após realizar uma requisição ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Eu tenho uma função em AJAX que enquanto carrega as informações do banco de dados para alimentar os `inputs` fica escrito "Carregando...". Caso não encontre nenhuma informação ele continua com este carregando escrito nos `inputs` até que eu atualize a página ou faça outra busca. Fiz um `if` no fim para limpar o `input` mas não estou conseguindo, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Segue código:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
//Funcao: functionjson
//Autor: Rafael Assmann <rafael@emperiumcode.com>
//Sinopse: Json para capturar código do produto e reali
//zar a busca no banco de dados e preencher os demais campos deste produto
//Parametro:
//   codProduto[] : código do produto digitado para pesquisa
//Retorno: nomeProduto[], qtProduto[] e valorProduto[] : informações do BD
//-----------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).delegate(".codigoProduto", "blur", function() {
         var parent = $(this).parent();
         var nomeProduto = parent.children("input:eq(1)");
         var qtProduto = parent.children("input:eq(2)");
         var valorProduto = parent.children("input:eq(3)");

             $( nomeProduto ).val('Carregando...');
             $( qtProduto ).val('Carregando...');
             $( valorProduto ).val('Carregando...');

             $.getJSON(
                 'function.php',
                 { codProduto: $( this ).val() },
                 function( json ) 
                 {
                      $( nomeProduto ).val( json.nomeProduto );
                      $( qtProduto ).val("1");
                      $( valorProduto ).val( json.valorProduto);
                     }
             );
                      if(json.nomeProduto == null)
                      $( nomeProduto ).val( " " ); // caso não encontre o produto no banco não esta caindo nesta condição para zerar o campo.   
     });
});
```

O arquivo de consulta ao banco de dados `function.php`:

```
<?php
    /**
     * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
     */
    function retorna( $nome, $db )
    {
        $sql = "SELECT `identProduto`, `codProduto`, `qtProduto`, `nomeProduto`, `valorProduto` FROM `t_estoque` WHERE `codProduto` = '{$nome}' ";

             $query = $db->query( $sql );

             $arr = Array();
             if( $query->num_rows )
             {
                 while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
                 {
                     $arr['nomeProduto'] = $dados->nomeProduto;
                     $arr['qtProduto'] = $dados->qtProduto;
                     $arr['valorProduto'] = $dados->valorProduto;
                 }
             }
             if($arr['qtProduto'] == 0){
                $arr['nomeProduto'] = 'sem estoque';
                $arr['qtProduto'] = '0';
             }
             return json_encode( $arr );
        }

    /* só se for enviado o parâmetro, que devolve os dados */
    if( isset($_GET['codProduto']) )
    {
        $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'buchm613_buchmann');
        echo retorna( filter ( $_GET['codProduto'] ), $db );
    }

    function filter( $var ){
        return $var;//a implementação desta, fica a cargo do leitor
    }
?>
```

Comment: Compara se ele é igual a vazio (" "), vazio é diferente de null

Comment: @RafaelDiasSoares Olá, ja tentei assim também mas não vai, por isso estou achando estranho... Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Neste caso não é diferente. Ambos resultam em false.

Comment: tente if(json.nomeProduto == undefined)

Comment: O console do navegador indica algum erro?

Comment: @RafaelDiasSoaresjá tinha testado com undefined e também não foi amigo... :/

Comment: @Renan não indica nenhum erro, funciona o ajax normalmente mas não limpa o input

Comment: Tenta fazer assim @RafaelAssmann, dá um console.log(json) e vê o que é retornado quando ele não encontra nada. Depois é só você validar.

Comment: @ThiagoThaison podes me dar um exemplo de como poderia usar o console.log(json) no meu código? obrigado!

Comment: Cara, eu tentaria dessa forma: Faria o meu retorno ajax tratar o `statusCode` caso não retorne nada (cod. 204), eu apenas limparia os campos do form. Caso ocorrer tudo bem (cod. 200) faria outra...

Comment: Pessoal, ainda não consegui achar uma solução para que eu possa avisar o usuário que o produto ainda esta em estoque ou que o produto não foi encontrado, @JoãoManolo como assim statusCode, podes postar um exemplo? obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelAssmann Fiz algumas edições na pergunta, você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39649/revisions) caso não apresente melhorias.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está no lugar em que colocou a condição. Você colocou fora da requisição, e como o JS irá executar de forma assíncrona, a sua condição executa antes do retorno do seu servidor.

Para executar no momento correto, você precisa adicionar a condição dentro da função de callback. Como ficaria sua chamada:

```
$.getJSON(
    'function.php',
    { codProduto: $( this ).val() },
    function( json ) 
    {
        $( nomeProduto ).val( json.nomeProduto );
        $( qtProduto ).val("1");
        $( valorProduto ).val( json.valorProduto);

        if(json.nomeProduto == null)
            $( nomeProduto ).val( "" );
    }
);
```

Comment: não obteve resultado desta forma amigo :/

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
if(json.length < 1){
  $(nomeProduto).empty();
}

ou 

if(!json.nomeProduto){
  $(nomeProduto).empty();
}
```

Comment: Olá @vcrzy tentei implementar desta forma mas não obtive sucesso, inseri o IF no mesmo lugar que esta na pergunta, tens mais alguma alternativa?

Comment: olá Rafael, 
Pelo que entendi seu objetivo é localizar os dados no banco ou limpar o campo caso não consiga.

Caso seja isso você pode adicionar um listener no evento complete do ajax fazendo com que assim seja disparada uma função quando o script terminar, esta pode checar se foi um sucesso ou uma falha e determinar o que fazer.

O jQuery que acredito você esteja usando deve prover este método para chamadas ajax, assim como outros dois métodos, os success e o error, ai é uma questão de escolher como você irá tratar a sua saida.

Comment: Vale lembrar que o success é disparado quando não detecta erros na requisição PHP, se eu puder recomendar eu recomendaria retornar um json com uma lista vazia e faria a checagem depois que a requisição terminasse. Eu evitaria alterar o código HTTP que é retornado para evitar problemas futuros, por exemplo, mudar para 404 se não encontrar resultados no futuro pode mascarar o fato do arquivo ter sido deletado, e mudar para outro pode mascarar futuros problemas também.